# Error: Failed to lookup view "layout" in views directory

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am getting the error like `Error: Failed to lookup view "layout" in views directory`. Below is the source code of the files as well as the folder structure.

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
//require express
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')

//Setting the View Engine as EJS
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(expressLayouts)

//Specifying the router file
var router = require('./routes')
app.use('/', router)

//Starting a server on port 8004
app.listen(8004, function () {
    console.log('Server is running at port 8004...!');
})
```

**routes.js**

```
    //require express
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

//creating a router object
var router = express.Router()

//export these routes to other files
module.exports = router


//Routes
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
})
```

This is the formHandling folder structure:

[image: This is the formHandling folder structure]

Answer (score 0):

Remove app.use(expresslayouts).
The express-ejs-layouts module is used to avoid duplication of code when there are multiple html pages. In the above code there is only one html page, so  express-ejs-layouts is not required.